# How to insert \N and tab with string in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

I want to add a string that contain \N and a tab in the starting, i want to add this string into mysql database. And also want to fetch the same string using php. I did imported that type of string using csv file, but problem arises when i try to fetch that string.

Exmaple string : "\N    Ada"

Mysql query :

```
$sql = "select `COL 1`, `COL 2` from `".$db_table."` where `".$db_column." like '\N\t".$keyword."%'";
```

$Keyword is the string with \N and a tab

Comment: Do you mean `"\n"` for a newline rather than `"\N"`?

Comment: Note that escape sequences are case-sensitive

Comment: You can use "\n" and make sure it is not being displayed in html tag such as: <div>. otherwise, you can use "</br>" in your string instead of "/n"

Comment: @MarkBaker Its not for newline, i just want to add it as a part of string. It need to be displayed along with other text with a tab space in between.

Comment: If you want a literal `\N` in your string, then you have to escape the "\" using `"\\N"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by concatenating the \N and tab to the variable. Earlier i was concatenating this string in the query itself. Still don't know the root cause, but concatenating that string to the variable seem to fix the problem.